# Toggle div when text input has pattern match

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show a div when someone has entered the correct answer into a text field. I'm using CSS psuedo selectors to hide the div when the field is invalid, but an empty field counts as valid, which shows the div before anything has been entered.

```
input:invalid + #next {
  display:none;
}

input:valid + #next {
  display:block;
}
```

```
<form>
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" pattern="1234">
  <div id="next">SUCCESS</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you just need to add `required` attribute so that some value should be needed before validating the input

```css
input:invalid + #next {
  display:none;
}

input:valid + #next {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" pattern="1234" required>
  <div id="next">SUCCESS</div>
</form>
```

Comment: if you don't want to use 'required', you can try with 

input:not(:valid) + #next {
  display:none;
}